# Passing javascript values to php

Tags: javascript, php, csv

I have two text boxes (textbox1 and textbox2) and a csv file. Textbox1 corresponds to column 0 in the csv and similarly for textbox2 to column 1. I want to type a letter into textbox1, have it search through column 0 for a match of the first letter of that field and then once it finds a match, populates the corresponding value in textbox2. For example:

Col0, Col1
Dan, Smith
Andrew, White
Matt, Stevens

If I type a "d" in textbox1 it should populate textbox2 with "Smith"

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("firstName");

var textBox2 = document.getElementById("lastName");

var theValue = textBox2.value;

for(var i=0;i<15;i++)

{
   (open php tag) $a++; (close php tag)

   for(var j=0;j<3;j++)

   {

   theArray[i][j]=

   (open php tag)

      $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

      $data = array();

      $b++;

      while($row = fgetcsv($fp))

         $data[] = $row;

      echo $data[$a][$b];

   (close php tag)

   if(theArray[0][j].substring(0,1)==theValue)

      textBox.value = theArray[1][j];
}
```

Something tells me incrementing `$a` in a separate php tag wont talk with the other php tag. Yes/no?

Any help with this getting this code working would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your code and I don't see any AJAX, URL requests, or form submits in the JavaScript.  That being said, I don't see how your JavaScript will pass values to  PHP because the JavaScript is running in the client's browser and the PHP is executing on the server.

[How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: So I have to post the values?

Comment: @user2382321 You have to send the JavaScript values to the server somehow, or PHP can't access them.

Comment: K I've played around with it a little more. I am not actually passing any js variables to php, I'm only doing the reverse, but my code is crashing because for some reason it won't let me iterate $a and $b. If I set them equal to a value the code works. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2382321 When you do `$a++` you are only iterating the variable once, because there is no PHP loop (executing on server), only a JavaScript loop (executing in client browser).